# How to get string within single quotes but ignore " 's " and " 't "?

Tags: python, regex

I want to retrieve a string within single quotes, e.g. in the sentence:

```
Play 'My lady's on fire' by Ty Segall
```

I want to retrieve:

```
My lady's on fire
```

I want to ignore words with `'s` and `'t` like "don't" and "lady's":

I tried this:

```
re.findall(r"\s\'.*?\'", user_input)
```

But, I am getting:

```
[ 'My lady']
```

I want to get:

```
[My lady's on fire]
```

Comment: Try `(?:\s|^)'.*?'(?:\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/4yhoQV/1

Comment: Use `re.findall(r"\B'.*?'\B", s)`

Comment: Regex isn't really suitable for this. As a simple heuristic you can disregard single apostrophes inside of words like "word's" but that still won't correctly cope with e.g. the genitive "words'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`\B'(?:[^']*(?:'\b)?)+'`](https://regex101.com/r/G6BBVT/1)

```
\B assert position where \b does not match
' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
Non-capturing group (?:[^']*(?:'\b)?)+
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^']*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
Non-capturing group (?:'\b)?
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
\b assert position at a word boundary: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
' matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: Sorry, this got 'My lady's on fire' for me. Is there anyway to do .replace on all ' but not in words like "lady's"?

Comment: I forgot I could use .strip(" ' "), sorry. Thank you, worked a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex --- > `\b\s'(.*?)(?=\'\s|\'$)`
you can test it on https://pythex.org/

Python code :

`import re
user_input = "Play 'My lady's on fire' by Nipsey Hussle Play 'My lady's on fire'"
print(re.findall(r"\b\s'(.*?)(?=\'\s|\'$)",user_input))`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much! *and sorry to any Nipsey Hussle fans, I actually meant to say 'by Ty Segall' (not that it really matters for this problem though)

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that this does not work when there is no string after the string in single quotes e.g. "Play 'My lady's on fire' " with no words after it extracts nothing.

Comment: Use this regex ---------> \b\s'(.*?)(?=\'\s|\'$)
this will work even with no words after it, I just edited the Answer so you can check code

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirements, one alternative (probably not the most performant) is this one:

```
\'(?:(?!\'[^st]).)*\'
```

Essentially you are taking characters until you find a sequence that starts with `'` and not followed by an *s* or a *t*.

If you instead need the more general case where you consider word boundary, then look at the other answers.